# Conflict with WinUser.h

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, game-engine

I was working on my game made using SDL2 with visual studio 2019 and one time i recompiled my code I started getting conflict on my struct KillTimer

```cpp
#include <chrono>
using fseconds = std::chrono::duration<float>;
struct KillTimer
{
    fseconds duration;
};
```

with micosofts from "WinUser.h"(btw why microsoft dont have this in some namespace ¯_(ツ)_/¯)

```cpp
WINUSERAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
KillTimer(
    _In_opt_ HWND hWnd,
    _In_ UINT_PTR uIDEvent);
```

I dont include any windows header by myself (maybe it is included by one of my thirdparty libs i use) so is there any way I can remove this conflict without renaming or moving my class to namespace?

Comment: You need to determine if this winapi function is actually used "by one of [your] thirdparty libs", as the first order of business, in order to be able to figure out what to do about it. There isn't, unfortunately, a "make this problem go away" magic button in C++. You need to fully understand the nature of this conflict, in order to come up with any potential workarounds.

Comment: MS doesnt use namespaces for these because they are APIs for C language as well.

Comment: @ChrisMM  they could used prefixes like SDL does to eliminate this problem (╯ ͠° ͟ʖ ͡°)╯┻━┻ .

Comment: Why would they? The API has been around for decades. They aren't going to change it now, and people are able to easily work around it. You can rename your `KillTimer` to anything else.

Comment: I know that it is too late by now but still it was horrible idea at start to not add any prefix like others libs and potentialy force people to change lots of code once they add one header and things explode  :(.

Comment: After reverting some changes it appears it was spdlog which caused this

Comment: SDL should have been the ones to rename their struct. Not Microsoft renaming their API. It would essentially break all backwards compatibility whichever required the function.

Comment: What if adding `#define NOUSER` at the beginning of the source file that generates the error?

Comment: *why microsoft dont have this in some namespace* win32 is a C API and C doesn't have namespaces.

Comment: You might as well have declared it `struct printf`.  KillTimer has been in the Windows SDK as a C API since the early 90's. Possibly even as an OS/2 function in the 80's.  Face it, you need to rename your struct or create your own namespace for it.  Reminds me of the time I declared a variable named `sun` and spent hours trying to understand why the compiler was complaining that `1` was an rvalue that couldn't be assigned to. :)